# Rails find all entries of a Model. Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to find all database entries for a Model. The code is situated in corns.rake

```
task (:clean_database) do
    clients = Client.all
    puts "BLAAAAAAA"
    puts clients.inspect
end
```

When I run  this code I got this error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Client
```

Comment: May be your model class is not loaded in the task class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task needs environment to be loaded, so:

```
task clean_database: :environment do
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load your Rails environment in the rake task in order for it to know about your model classes (eg Client)

```
task(:clean_database => :environment) do
  ...
```

note also no space between `task` and `(` or you'll get a warning about dodgy parentheses.